# Why am I getting an IQueryable error with my LINQ Join statement for my KendoUI Grid in my ASP.NET Core 5 web application?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I have a KendoUI Grid bound to a SignalR data source, the action to read data from the database has a linq statement in it joining two tables together and yet, I'm getting an error on that statement of:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable> to
> 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyCompany.Data.PositionData>> An explicit
> conversation exists (are you missing a cast?)

The code for the action is as follows:

***PositionHub/Read***

```
public class ReadRequestData
{
    public int ViewId { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<PositionData> Read(ReadRequestData data)
{
    IQueryable<PositionData> positions = from position in _positionData.GetAll().Where(x => x.View_Id == data.ViewId)
        join all_vessels in _viewAllVessels.GetAll() on position.Vessel_Id equals all_vessels.Id
    select new {
        data = position
    };
    return positions;
}
```

To me, the code looks correct but I've now been staring at it for too long and I'm struggling to understand what the problem is.

Here is the code for the rest of my application

***The KendoUI Grid***

```
$('#position_grid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "signalr",
        autoSync: true,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    "Id": {
                        editable: false,
                        nullable: true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        transport: {
            parameterMap: parameters_position_grid,
            signalr: {
                promise: position_hub_start,
                hub: position_hub,
                server: {
                    read: "read",
                    update: "update",
                    create: "create",
                    destroy: "destroy"
                },
                client: {
                    read: "read",
                    update: "update",
                    create: "create",
                    destroy: "destroy"
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 1000
    },
    columns: generated_columns
});
```

***Parameter Map***

This passes an Id to the read action as a parameter to select data, it's fed by a dropdown box the user interacts with.

```
function parameters_position_grid(data, operation) {
    //Get the view id from local storage
    let viewId = localStorage["position_view"];
    //Check the operation type
    if (operation === "read") {
        //Set the parameter to the data
        //Must be a int
        data.ViewId = +viewId;        
    }
    return data;
}
```

I can see that it's perhaps the parameter 'ReadRequestData' because, if I remove that, the query works.  But I need that parameter and I'm sure how to build that into the action that has a join.

Comment: I doubt that this is your complete error message. The template parameter in the first IQueryable is missing and "explicit convers*at*ion" looks funny.

Comment: You're right, I've added "are you missing a cast" hopefully that helps. Cheers

Comment: No, I meant this one: "System.Linq.IQueryable>" - it is very probably "System.Linq.IQueryable<*sometype*>"

Comment: You declare variable `positions` as `IQueryable<PositionData>`, but then you do `select new { ... }`, so actually you are selecting anonymous type.

Comment: Replace `IQueryable<PositionData> positions ` with `var positions` then finally return `position.AsQueryable();`